# resize border in webbrowser component

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

When I edit a text in webbrowser component in C#, a border showing around it.
I want to edit the text without a border. When I click the text block twice, 
the border can be seen.

I want a source code that I click once on the text, it can be edited without showing a border.

The webbrowser component is in edit mode and I click on a text block or an image. Around the image there are eight boxes in order to resize.. When I click a text block, a div tag for example, the boxes also can be seen.. and I click twice, the text is editable with a border around it.. This border is not needed..

Comment: This is not an issue with the web browser control. It's an HTML/CSS issue. When you use a browser to edit, do you see a border?

Comment: This issue is with the webbrowser component.. See the text above.. Not with CSS or HTML..

Actually, this is a editor function inside the component.

Comment: The web browser control is just Internet Explorer. There is no "editor function" which is not part of some HTML page.

Comment: The webbrowser component is edit mode.. Do you undertand?
If you click an image.. there are six boxes around the image to resize.. The other function is for text editing inside a block tag, for example div..
These are not part of HTML or CSS

Comment: Sorry, you are either not using the web browser control, or else you have some add-on to IE. The web browser control does not have this functionality, I guarantee you.

Comment: Then what do you offer?

Comment: I offer you go find out what you're using. It's time for you to ask someone who knows what's going on.

Comment: I put a webbrowser component on a form and used this code, bellow. And then I could edit text and resize image..  


mshtmlDocument document = (mshtmlDocument)this.webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument;
mshtmlBody body = (mshtmlBody)document.body;
body.contentEditable = "true";

Comment: See? That was easy. `contentEditable = true;` This is identical to creating the HTML: `<body contentEditable="true">`.

Comment: Thank you! Anyway, how I could edit a div tag block in C# without the border.. I do not want to use a javascript inline editor because I want to resolve the problem with C# , change font style, font family, and add indent or align in a C# editor..